# Angular sending wrong date format to java and object can not be created in table

Tags: java, sql, angular

I have a coupon system in which a coupon bean in java has a date.sql startDate and endDate.
In angular, the coupon model has startDate:Date and endDate:Date in it's constructor.
When I display it on the website it shows as july 30th 2019( in my local language) so when I click the purchase button i get an error in the console:
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.sql.Date` from String "ֳ—ֵ¾ֳ—ֲ¨ֳ—ֲ¥ 13, 1991": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'ֳ—ֵ¾ֳ—ֲ¨ֳ—ֲ¥ 13, 1991': Cannot parse date "ֳ—ֵ¾ֳ—ֲ¨ֳ—ֲ¥ 13, 1991": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 73] (through reference chain: beans.Coupon["startDate"])

I have tried displaying it with a pipe- {{value | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
but in this way, i couldnt even display it on the website anymore.

```
 </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let c of coupons">

      <td>{{c.startDate}}</td>
      <td>{{c.endDate}}</td>
      <td>{{c.amount}}</td>
     coupon model:

    public constructor(
        public id?:number,public title?:string,public message?:string,public image?:string,public startDate?:Date,
        public endDate?:Date,public amount?:number,public price?:number,public type?:Coupontypes){}

}

Java
private Date startDate, endDate;
```

I guess i can not purchase a coupon because it creats the JSON with string values instead of yyyy-MM-dd like the server expects to recieve.

Comment: what format is the date in currently? if the date pipe isn't working to display it then it probably is not in a standard format and you may need to manipulate it in order to get it formatted correctly.

Comment: 2019, 14 יולי, its in hebrew but basicly 2019,july 14th

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the error is coming from your Java program. You are sending a date value in a format that it does not expect. Changing how you view the date in the html will not change the actual value. If you are using Angular 6+ you can do something like the following to transform the date to the format it is expecting:

```
    import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

    class MyService {

      constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

      transformDate(date) {
        return formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', this.locale);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think i didn't understand what to do.
I generated a new class that looks like this:
`code`
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

class MyService {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', this.locale);
  }
}
`code`
but it didnt affect the display at all, what did i do wrong? i'm kind of an angular newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the date as a String in a agreed format to the API.
In API parse it and save to DB.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).